# Using a recursive macro to write the arguments of a function

Tags: c++, recursion, macros

Is it possible to use a recursive macro to write as many function arguments as required. For example:

```
void foo( const char (&row1)[3] , const char (&row2)[3] , const char (&row3)[3] )
{
}

void foo( const char (&row1)[3] , const char (&row2)[3] , const char (&row3)[3] , const char (&row4)[3] , const char (&row5)[3] , const char (&row6)[3] )
{
}
```

I am aware that variadic templates were introduced to solve problems like this but I am limited to C++98 ATM.

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look at the [boost::preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/) library which gives you a whole preprocessing toolkit. It provides preprocessor metaprogramming tools including repetition and recursion.

You can see an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14594260/28275).

Comment: Thanks. What part of the preprocessor library should I pay close attention to? I am not at all familiar with the library and but like to solve the problem ASAP.

Comment: @Olumide you could take a look at ENUM_BINARY_PARAMS http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/enum_binary_params.html

Answer (score 0):

Macros can't be recursive, since macro expansion won't expand the name of a macro in the process of being expanded.  C++11 did introduce the concept of macros with a variable number of arguments, using `__VA_ARGS__`, but I don't know too much about it.  (I use very few macros.)

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, the developer would create a set of macros, each with a different number of arguments:

```
#define foo1(arg1)
#define foo2(arg1, arg2)
#define foo3(arg1, arg2, arg3)
...
```