# How to use template when number of arguments are not known?

Tags: c++, templates, arguments

I have refered this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16338804/1105805) to meet my requirement .
But when I am trying to implement the same in my code, it is throwing an error.

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void fun(T t, Args... args)
{
    cout << t;
}
int main()
{
    fun(1, 2.0, "Ranjan", "hi");//Error happens here
return 0;
}
```

The error at `fun()` is `template<class T, <error type>>`

What is going wrong here?

Comment: compiles for me fine (with some warnings), and executes good. What is the error?

Comment: Compiles fine with g++ (http://ideone.com/iqHvqW). What compiler are you using and how? Variadic templates where added in c++11.

Comment: Have you enabled c++11 flag? (e.g. `-std=c++11`)?

Comment: @iammilind: I am using visual studio 2010 ultimate edition

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak, that does not support variadic templates and only supports a subset of the c++11 features.

Comment: @iammilind: Where is the C++11 flag in VS 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS2010 does not support variadic templates. See [C++11 Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx). VS2012 does not support it either, according to that page, so upgrading is not a solution at the moment.

Search for *c++03 mimic variadic templates* to determine if there is an alternative (one example from this site: [How to implement "Variadic Template" with pre-c++0x(VS2008)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683041/how-to-implement-variadic-template-with-pre-c0xvs2008)).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using only the first, and not other template arguments. The g++ warning clearly explains it.

This example uses all arguments, and add a function for no arguments :

```
#include <iostream>

void fun()
{
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void fun(T t, Args... args)
{
    std::cout << t;
    fun(args...);
}
int main()
{
    fun(1, 2.0, "Ranjan", "hi");//Error happens here
}
```